# Install swagger-php and Composer in Linux Centos 7

Tags: swagger, centos7, swagger-php

I`m trying to find the steps for installing swagger-php and Composer in Linux Centos7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CentOS 7 is just another linux distribution, so please follow general installation steps for all unix/linux machines.

1. For composer Linux install:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos

2. After installing composer into your Centos7 machine, please follow this steps:

http://zircote.com/swagger-php/Getting-started.html#installation